# Pentaho Server - "Stuck" DB connections

Tags: jdbc, pentaho

Software: Pentaho Server CE 9.3

Issue: All database connections suddenly stopped working, preventing successful execution of Jobs and Transformations scheduled in the software. Even after attempting to connect using other programs such as DBEAVER and SQLDEVELOPER, the issue still persisted. It appears that too many database connections may be stuck, causing the issue.

We use MYSQL, Oracle, and SQL Server in our database environment.
Could Someone Advise how can i start to look this up.
right now what we do is restart the server and it "works" again.

Sample of error log (path and file names redacted):

> 2023-04-13 16:10:01.682 INFO  <teste - Insert / update> [/home/---/---/---.ktr]  Finished processing (I=5, O=0, R=5, W=5, U=0, E=0)
> 2023-04-13 16:12:00.357 INFO  <PentahoQuartzScheduler_Worker-10> [/home/---/---/---/---.ktr]  Expedindo in?cio para transforma??o [---]
> 2023-04-13 16:12:00.608 ERROR <init of SELECT DADOS MYSQL.0 (Thread-3727)> [/home/---/---/---/---.ktr]  An error occurred, processing will be stopped:
> Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
>
> Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>
> 2023-04-13 16:12:00.608 ERROR <init of SELECT DADOS MYSQL.0 (Thread-3727)> [/home/---/---/---/---.ktr]  Erro inicializando step [SELECT DADOS MYSQL]
> 2023-04-13 16:12:00.620 ERROR <init of INS/UPD ---.0 (Thread-3728)> [/home/---/---/---/---.ktr]  An error occurred during initialization, processing will be stopped:
> Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
>
> Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
> Erro de ES: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=YKDC8ZbJTPCaAMS8ymsO0Q==)
>
> 2023-04-13 16:12:00.620 ERROR <init of INS/UPD ---.0 (Thread-3728)> [/home/---.ktr]  Erro inicializando step [INS/UPD ---]
> 2023-04-13 16:12:00.621 ERROR <init of UPDATE ---.0 (Thread-3729)> [/home/---/---/---/---.ktr]  An error occurred during initialization, processing will be stopped:
> Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
>
> Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Found on a forum that increasing the windows "port" cap, but did not change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Aperantly the issue was not on the pnetaho server, but another program thar wasn't closing the connections correctly,
however i made a Job that every x min run a check if the DB connections are avaible, if no, then restart the server.